Decomposing physical degrees of freedom for spin-3 (Schwartz)
In section 8.7.2 of Schwartz, he decomposes the polarization vector for a massive spin-2 particle into 2 transverse and 3 longitudinal components, $$h_{\mu\nu} = h^T_{\mu\nu} + \partial_\mu (\pi^T_\nu + \partial_\nu \pi^L) + \partial_\nu (\pi^T_\mu + \partial_\mu \pi^L),$$ with $\partial_\mu h^T_{\mu\nu} = 0$ and $\partial_\mu \pi^T_\mu = 0$. So the three physical longitudinal modes are all contained in $\pi^T_\mu$. But it's not clear to me what object the two transverse modes are contained in, or what the role of $\pi^L$ is supposed to place (my first thought was that the $L$ denoted a longitudinal mode, which cannot be right given the interpretation of $\pi^T_\mu$.
Further, one of the exercises requires doing a similar decomposition of a spin-3 massive particle. In that case, I am even less sure about where the degrees of freedom are. One can define a rank-3 tensor $Z_{\mu\nu\rho} = Z^T_{\mu\nu\rho} + \partial_\mu h_{\nu\rho} + \partial_\nu h_{\rho\mu} + \partial_\rho h_{\mu\nu}$, and then decompose $h_{\mu\nu}$ as with the spin-2 particle. In that case, where are the 5 physical longitudinal modes?

$h_{\mu\nu}$ has 5 d.o.f./modes. 2 of them are transverse, in $h_{\mu\nu}^T$, and 3 are longitudinal in the following expressions in the parentheses, only 3 because the imagined 4th is pruned away by $\partial\cdot \pi$.
